# Парсинг "прогруженной" страницы python, requests

Tags: javascript, python, html, парсер, requests

Такая проблема - мне нужно спарсить с google картинок изображение кот в высоком качестве, для этого я открываю ссылку в параметрах которой id картинки, тем самым получаю её версию в высоком качестве (пример - `https://www.google.com/search?q=кот&hl=tt&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALiCzsbG5z3WdiIBMmJpVA4tS5cNaUNuvA%3A1658298357600&source=hp&biw=2519&bih=1330&ei=9Z_XYqyrIsmHwPAPoIqgsAU&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYteuBSdbNazrU2Hog2F8dnZvuaR5W9_h&ved=0ahUKEwjs-aLk6ob5AhXJAxAIHSAFCFYQ4dUDCAY&uact=5&oq=кот&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzoHCCMQ6gIQJ1C-CljND2CuEmgBcAB4AIABQIgBtwGSAQEzmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWewAQo&sclient=img#imgrc=1UUbQn2ml_olWM`) но как я понял, html код на сервере не содержит элемент с ссылкой изображение а подгружает его уже js так вот вопрос - как можно исправить эту проблему (конкретно для google картинок) без selenium?
Вот текущий код -

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from random import choice

name = "кот"
url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={name}&client=opera&hs=nkI&hl=ru&sxsrf=APq-WBuUWCpyLYYduHWl9vqF9dG_IIvdpg:1649445742756&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizzsqcmIX3AhVM-yoKHcKBCg0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=2519&bih=1299&dpr=1"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "мой юзер агент"
}

r = req.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BS(r.text, "html.parser")
imgs = list()

for id in soup.select("div", class_="isv-r PNCib MSM1fd BUooTd"):
    imgs.append(id.get("data-id"))

imgs = list(set(imgs))
if None in imgs:
    imgs.remove(None)

#id = choice(imgs)
id = "S5jBt3Lp984OCM"  # пока что работаю с конкретной картинкой




url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={name}&client=opera-gx&hs=XcT&sxsrf=ALiCzsYXEnUBcedkSFWmbdVAf4CQWDuzew:1658225914940&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU2vf03IT5AhXRi8MKHcTfC5UQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=2519&bih=1330&dpr=1#imgrc=kUIe1rLXX0NjAM"

r = req.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BS(r.text, "html.parser")

imgs = list()

for img in soup.select("img", class_="rg_i Q4LuWd"):
    imgs.append(img)

imgs = list(set(imgs))
if None in imgs:
    imgs.remove(None)

print(imgs)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "html код на сервере не содержит элемент с ссылкой изображение" откуда такая увереность?

Comment: спарсив код проверил, div с картинкой появляется после прогрузки (то что должно было бы появиться я обвел https://imgur.com/a/Y41Kc0R)

Comment: @АндрейПристягин Вот я на пример утверждаю на 100%, что "html код на сервере" который скачал req.get(url, headers=headers) содержит ссылки на изображенния в количестве 100 штук

Comment: конкретно того что я указал нет, все которые есть это превью в низком качестве

Comment: префью: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSePgBrQmTIqE5zRAvGCH8yVYTU9AlorGt35WLE93tfXxRNQQhhX4wp-6c5Hr-K4IO_2jg&usqp=CAU
описанние: Эти глаза — не фотошоп! Самый красивый кот в мире родился в питомнике  челябинки - KP.Ru
сайт: https://www.chel.kp.ru/daily/27061.4/4128529/
картинка https://s13.stc.yc.kpcdn.net/share/i/instagram/B44solahwlo/wr-1280.webp
все это есть в html коде

Comment: Эм я сказал что мне надо в исходном качестве (1200x1200) а то что есть превью в маленьком качестве ( то что ты скинул(а) ) в html я и так знаю

Comment: Так у вас запросе и не указано какого качества вам надо. По умалчиванию любой.

Comment: `Такая проблема - мне нужно спарсить с google картинок изображение кота в высоком качестве` первое предложение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=кот&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:l', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
dd = soup.find('script', string=re.compile("key: 'ds:1'")).text.strip()[20:-2]
dd = dd.replace(": '", ': "').replace("',", '",').replace('key:', '"key":').replace('hash:', '"hash":').\
    replace('data:', '"data":').replace('sideChannel:', '"sideChannel":')

z = json.loads(dd)
for img_links in z['data'][31][0][12][2]:
    try:
        url, x, y = img_links[1][3]
        if x >= 1200 and y >= 1200:
            print(x, 'X', y, url)
    except Exception:
        continue

1387 X 1200 https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Felis_silvestris_silvestris.jpg/1200px-Felis_silvestris_silvestris.jpg
1440 X 1920 https://cdnn21.img.ria.ru/images/07e5/06/18/1738448523_0:21:864:669_1920x0_80_0_0_9920bbedf3cb1a14b1358e0677d01106.jpg
.....
1281 X 1920 http://blog.translate.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/fat-cat-6082769_1920.jpg
1500 X 2000 https://vsluh.ru/upload/iblock/371/kbdpkc977sxmg11ujb5vrygnasmmsjgr.jpg
1500 X 1500 https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/lookaside/crawler/media/?media_id=731717787465455
```

Бонус

```
for s in z['data'][1][0][0][1]:
    print(s[0], f"https://www.google.com{s[2]}")

сфинкс https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82&tbm=isch&chips=q:%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82,g_1:%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%81:gzUMf_Ddcok%3D
рыжий https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82&tbm=isch&chips=q:%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82,g_1:%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9:IbspG5mKFbs%3D
....
русский https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82&tbm=isch&chips=q:%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82,g_1:%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9:Ipy01joVeO8%3D
маленький https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82&tbm=isch&chips=q:%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82,g_1:%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9:spAFfzZaIDQ%3D
```

Comment: спасибо, проверю отпишусь

Comment: только хотел написать про ошибку с json а вы уже исправили  в любом случае спасибо