# Python - BeautifulSoup - поиск по выдаче

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Всем привет. В общем что я пытаюсь сделать (и пытаюсь неправильно! Поэтому благодарен за любую помощь)

Суть такая - я хочу извлечь из гугла картинку по ключевому запросу.
Сейчас моя абракадабра стопорится на следующей задаче:

```
testing_images = soup.find_all('img', attrs={'class':'rg_i Q4LuWd'})
 links=[]
 for x in testing_images:
    if x['src']:
       links+=[x['src']]
```

Проблема в проверке внутри цикла.
Если пишу if 'src' in x: не происходит ничего (то есть вот вообще ничего)

Если пишу if x['src']!=None или любую другую конструкцию то выбрасывает ошибку.
Проблема в том что в выдаче бывает не только 'src' но и 'data-src', и вот я не могу никак проверить что из двух попадается в выдаче.

А вообще если у вас есть код способный вытащить картинку из поисковой выдачи гугла - буду страшно благодарен если вы поделитесь)

Comment: Ваша абракадабра бессильна против магий гугла.

Comment: добавь пример содержимого "testing_images" (кнопка "Править" под вопросом)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1431770/470333