# Python BeautifulSoup получить массив необходимых изображений

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, google-search

Я написал вот такой код:

```
import requests
from json import loads
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})

r = s.get('https://www.google.ru/search?q=яблоко&tbm=isch')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Помогите пожалуйста с *soup* получить список изображений в виде списка с результата моего запроса, которые начинаются на `https:` и заканчиваются на `.jpeg`. Вот пример одной такой картинки: `https://n1s1.hsmedia.ru/e8/51/6f/e8516f2acb78da50af1bc56746074bf9/728x542_1_6da41869d71991d2029232c9f81dfd46@1300x968_0xac120003_14909260701652800883.jpeg`

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1431770/470333

Comment: @СергейШ я попробовал код по ссылке, но он там уже не рабочий, выдает ошибку ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Ну вы же смотрели, что там печатается? Там сплошной `JavaScript`. Нужен какой-то движок, который будет рендерить этот `JS` в `HTML`. Например, `Selenium`.

Comment: @CrazyElf я там разобрался, привел код в рабочий выд, но увы, вывод картином делается в очень меленьком разрешении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BS` тут не справится, потому что содержание страницы - сплошной `JavaScript`, его нужно чем-то рендерить, каким-то браузерным движком, например `Selenium`. Единственное, что тут можно сделать - поискать нужные ссылки регуляркой прямо в тексте страницы:

```
re_jpeg = re.compile(r'"http[^"]+.jpeg"')
print(re_jpeg.findall(r.text))
```

Вывод:

```
['"https://n1s1.hsmedia.ru/e8/51/6f/e8516f2acb78da50af1bc56746074bf9/728x542_1_6da41869d71991d2029232c9f81dfd46@1300x968_0xac120003_14909260701652800883.jpeg"',
 '"https://n1s1.hsmedia.ru/4c/e6/48/4ce648215d3c31f3edd68d384119c962/728x543_1_f2870b4ca764c3b0940b8c8a4e875406@1300x969_0xac120003_7910508621652800852.jpeg"',
 '"https://fruit-time.ua/images/cache/blog/vr-cc95dd2c-1ca6-4543-8c0a-e14993edaae5-1110x740r.jpeg"']
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что мне нужно!